# Retrieve and compare two excel file using C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have to compare two Excel files having different number of sheets, different number of columns/rows

**Sheet1**:

```
       A          B         
---------------------
1     123       AB 
2     124       AB  
3     125       AB  
4     126       AB
```

```html
**Sheet2**:

           A          B         
    ------------------------
    1     123        
    2     124        
    3     125        
    4     126
```

Output:

```html
Sheet1
------
       A          B         
1     123       AB 
2     124       AB  
3     125       AB  
4     126       AB
```

Note:

I would like to retrieve data from sheet1 to sheet2 for column B

I can able to export data from Excel sheet using following code, but I have try to get data from two excel sheet and compare from sheet1 to sheet2 for column B.

Thanks

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
//using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Train1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //private dynamic data1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Subbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.Columns.Add("Test");
            //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            string Import_FileName = txtFileName.Text;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
            
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + Import_FileName + ";Extended Properties= \"Excel 12.0;HDR=yes\"";
            }
            
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PLese choose correct excel file format");
            }


            OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]");
            comm.Connection = conn;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = comm;
            da.Fill(ds);
            System.Reflection.Missing miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
            string timeMark = DateTime.Now.ToString(" - yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output" + timeMark + ".xlsx");
            //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location  
            Excel.Workbooks books = (Excel.Workbooks)excelApp.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = (Excel.Workbook)books.Add(miss);

            foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {   
                //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
                excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;
                
                for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                    }
                }


                excelWorkBook.SaveAs(FilePath, miss, miss, miss, miss, miss, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, miss, miss);
                excelWorkBook.Close(false, miss, miss);
                MessageBox.Show("Output has been generated");
                //excelWorkBook.Save();  
                books.Close();
                excelApp.Quit();
            }
        }



        private void butbrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog test1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            test1.ShowDialog();
            txtFileName.Text = test1.FileName;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog test2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            test2.ShowDialog();
            textsheet2.Text = test2.FileName;
           
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: use OpenXml or ClosedXml to work with Excel files in C#